# Update a HTML tag after an interval

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to make an HTML5 clock as my first project, but I am having problems with updating the .innerHTML property every second, though console.log works just fine.
Here is my main.js:

```
     var baseDate = new Date();
    var seconds =   baseDate.getSeconds();
    var secondsElement = document.getElementsByClassName("seconds");

 setInterval(function() {secondsElement.innerHTML = seconds;
        console.log(seconds);}, 1000);
```

I also checked everything for typos regarding class names, but found nothing.

Comment: The value of `seconds` doesn't change, so you're just setting it to the same thing each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing the same time every time. You need to update the time inside the interval, otherwise the variable will never change :

```
setInterval(function() {
    var baseDate       = new Date(),
        seconds        = baseDate.getSeconds(),
        secondsElement = document.getElementsByClassName("seconds")[0];
    secondsElement.innerHTML = seconds;
}, 1000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DtBCW/)

Comment: What a pervasive "coding style" certain tools have been able to propagate .. (the single `var`). However, this should work correctly and explains the problem.

Comment: JSLint and Crockford which returns "Combine this with the previous 'var' statement" as an "error" (so much misguided hubris lurks yonder) for `var a = 1; var b = 2;` with default settings. :(

Comment: It's better to put `secondsElement` outside the `setInterval`.